# Filereader without user interaction Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to write this software where I am able to load a table from an excel file. However, I would like the loading of the file to become automated when the page is loaded. 
I am using an input type button to handle the event and I am looking to remove this from page since the file I want to use is fixed will only be used for monitoring data.

```js
var wb;
$('#input-excel2').change(function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    wb = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    });
    var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb, {
      sheet: "Vans in Repair",
      type: 'binary',
      bookType: 'html'
    });
    $('#NW')[0].innerHTML += htmlstr;
    console.log(htmlstr);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script lang="javascript" src="sheetjs/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar"><span>Monitoring software </span></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 quad">
    <div id='NW'>
      <input type="file" id="input-excel2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really nice question. But before all maybe you can format your snippet with correct indentations as well as removing `</div>` after the first `<script>` tag -as it has no opening tag

Comment: Thanks, @vahdet I am a bit confused since I haven't worked on Html for quite a long time

Comment: I guess using `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR_CODE_HERE });` should do your work

Comment: this is not possible for a good reason. If you could access a file without a user interaction that would be horrible for security.

Comment: Thank you @Piyush that solves my problem of triggering the event!!!

Comment: @Thomas good point but I am only interested in just loading the file from its file path instead of going through the prompts. I hope I find a workaround

Comment: "I am only interested in just loading the file from its file path"....so what? That's not any different from what Thomas is describing. The file belongs to the user, not to your web application. It has no right to take that file (or any other) without the user's direct consent and involvement. In fact, you cannot even guarantee that the file is in the correct location, or even that the file path is correct (file paths in Windows and Mac are written very differently, for example).

Comment: What you want is both forbidden and also impractical, for very good reasons. Hackers and criminals would have a wonderful time stealing data if this feature was allowed.

Comment: If you want a program which can read directly from the user's device without user interaction, then you need to write a desktop application instead of a browser-based application. Then the user must download and execute it directly on their machine, which is effectively a way of them giving consent to your program to read whatever data it needs, since they allowed the app to run in the first place. (This is different to viewing a web page, where new functionality can be introduced each time without warning, so the user cannot always know what to expect or what they agreed to).